# Resilience of WinRar format for storage

Tags: hard-drive, archiving, rar

I have a folder with plenty of files (~10k small files), in total ~50MB in size. It's some "old stuff" I actually dont need anymore but still wanna keep. As I'm syncing a parent folder of this folder to some cloud storage, it always takes quite a while until this folder with all the small files is scanned and compared w.r.t changes.

I could set some exclude-rule to not scan this folder, but that gets a bit ugly because I have a few of those "old" folders with plenty of coding files.

Instead, I thought to create a WinRar archive with nearly no compression (setting "Normal" or maybe even "Fast") and 20% of recovery information, solid archiv and also restricting change to the Archive.

Is this a good idea or is this sort of archiving prone to errors in case my HDD has some corrupt sectors?

Thanks

Comment: Your actual problem is lack of backups. They're a proven way to protect data from bad sectors, bit rot, user mistakes, hardware failures, software bugs and malware. If you're worried about data loss, come up with a reliable backup strategy instead of packing stuff into redundant RARs hoping they won't get damaged enough to be unrecoverable.

Comment: No, actually I have plenty of backups, 2*1TB drives internally, syncing each other, than regularly once per month on some external 1TB drive and additionally syncing via Cryptomator into Dropbox (only important files). But for all those one-way Backups a SyncTool is used, which is SyncBack Pro in my case. And syncing those folders takes ages because of those huge amounts of files. So I just wanted to rar them...

Comment: That's great. So if you have backups, why worry about bad sectors? You can always restore from a copy.

Comment: It'*s not only about bad sectors. It's the general part of the question, about whether those type of archives are prone to errors, maybe in any other way. But yeah, I shouldnt have specialized the question only wrt bad sectors, but just in general.

Comment: Argh, I've re-written this many times, there is so much to say!  Instead, I'm just going to say that you need to better understand the flaws with your current storage and backup, and then look to improve it.  For instance, ask yourself if you had better local storage (ZFS or RAID, etc), would you even need to backup those files?

Comment: And why WinRAR? There are numerous better (compression, support, longevity) compression/storage formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is good for speed but cannot be answered directly as the file format of a rar archive is not documented. 
As a rar archive is able to contain a hierarchical file structure and file metadata, a rar archive is a file system itself, like an ISO file for instance.

Depending on its internal organisation it is prone to dammage if it organizes file positions in a FATxx (file allocation table) manner which is prone to direct hits like the reactor trench in Star Wars I or much better like in NTFS (cluster lists in individual MFT entries).

The Winrar documentation does not state anything about the content being equally resilient against losses.

Then Winrar help file states:
[...
The recovery record contains up to 524288 recovery sectors. If data is damaged **continuously**, then each recovery sector is able to recover 512 bytes of damaged information. This value may be lower in cases of multiple damage.
...]

and
[...
The recovery record increases the size of an archive. The size of the recovery record may be approximately determined by the formula:

{archive size}/256 + {number of recovery sectors} * 512 bytes.
...]

Your talking about a size of 50MB. With today's drives with a physical sector size of 4096 bytes regardless of 512 byte emulation we are talking about a storage need of 12500 sectors for your file. How high do you consider the probability of a non-continuous double sector loss in your group of 12500 sectors?

To find out, you might want to test that case as follows:

1. Pack your archive
2. Zero out two non-continuous sectors (two 4096 byte areas) in your file
3. Repair it
4. Unpack it
5. Compare with your source.

Keep in mind that the data of a file is not necessarily stored at the beginning of a physical sector (p.e. NTFS files start with the magic word "FILE", followed by other information before the data section with the file data beginns).

21.5.2020: replaced the "bigger than" and "smaller than" symbols by brackets because they were hiding the the content of the formula

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer contains an outdated information about Winrar recovery record. That information is only true for RAR 4.x and older versions. RAR 5.0 has new recovery record.

The version 5.00 changelog states:

"New recovery record is not based on 512 byte sectors anymore and incorporates more complicated data structures. So it is impossible to specify its size in sectors. For RAR 5.0 archives the parameter of -rr[N] switch and rr[N] command is always treated as a percent of archive size regardless of presence of % character. Typically N% recovery record can repair up to N% of continuously damaged data and increases the archive size by only slightly more than N%. Ability to fix multiple damages is proportional to N."

Source (scroll down to Version 5.00):
https://www.rarlab.com/rarnew.htm